# Need help portraying a character's personality in my First Person POV Narrative

Tags: creative-writing

I'm writing a First-Person POV story that is following the main protagonist. I'm trying to get to the main plot, but I can't do that without making the story enticing enough to make the readers want to keep reading up to that point, obviously. I'm not sure how to, but I want to clearly show my main characters arrogance through his dialogue and actions, but like I said I'm not sure how to. If it helps, here's some info:

**Plot Summary**
Hunter Shiro, a 15-year-old male, lived a pretty uneventful life until he got into a heated argument with his close friend, Joey. The argument ends in a falling out, but their falling out doesn't last long as Hunter realises they are in danger. Joey is oblivious to the serial killer approaching him, so Hunter pushes him out of the way and dies, something he never thought he'd do. When he opened his eyes again he was in a dark void with only him and the beautiful angel, Lucy. She tells Hunter that a dreadful force of evil has been born on Earth and only he can stop it. Hunter is re-born onto Earth (Thus the name of the story, Re-Birth.) with all of the memories of his past life and is tasked with removing this 'evil' from it.

**About Hunter**

Hunter is a tanned male with azure eyes and jet black hair. Ever since his father passed away, he and his mother would sit in the house and barely communicate. He often lets his arrogance get the better of him and, even though he doesn't like to admit it, he is overly caring (Meaning he cares about others, even if he doesn't know them.). After his death, Hunter begins to change his ways and also his personality.

I don't need to worry about his new, changed personality just yet; his arrogant persona is what I need. Like I asked before, I need to know the best ways to show his arrogance through his character. Anyone know how I can do this effectively? I just feel like I won't do it very well. If I need to write some more information then let me know and I will comment to you what you need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I'm going to assume you've read plenty of First Person PoV novels?

I'm reading something that I need to read for an assignment. It's a PoV novel in First Person, and you know the character is an infuriating, pompous ass just from some of the interactions he has. He narrates meeting one of the other main characters and talks about her in a tone that sounds like it could be a compliment, but turns out is not - he says she'd look better in a her wax coat and wellies than an evening dress. It's a really nasty paragraph that shows up what an ass this character actually is.

The compulsion in continuing to read the character comes from wanting to get to the bottom of the mystery of the novel. So, also, are your circumstances compelling enough as well.

But I'd honestly go back to some first person novels first.

Comment: Any suggestions on what ones I should read?

Comment: I'm not a big first person PoV reader - it's one of my least favourite, so at the moment my scope of FP PoV is limited to what I've recently read for my studies. But if you are interested, the book I am talking about in my post is The Little Stranger by Sarah Walters. There is actually, also, The Last by Hanna Jameson, her male 1stPoV character is a right piece of work as well.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! I really appreciate this. I'll make sure to read them both before I continue writing.